# How to swap substrings of a string in golang?

Tags: string, go, swap

I am trying to learn Go-lang and for this reason playing around with strings in Go. But I am unable to perform correct swapping of sub-strings in a string.

**My code is:**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    mystr := "I have an apple but not a mango, and she has a mango but not an apple"
    fmt.Println(mystr)
    mystr = strings.ReplaceAll(mystr, "apple", "(apple)")
    mystr = strings.ReplaceAll(mystr, "mango", "apple")
    mystr = strings.ReplaceAll(mystr, "(apple)", "mango")
    fmt.Println(mystr)
    mystr = strings.ReplaceAll(mystr, "an", "(a)")
    mystr = strings.ReplaceAll(mystr, "a", "an")
    mystr = strings.ReplaceAll(mystr, "(an)", "a")
    fmt.Println(mystr)
}
```

**Output:**

```
I have an apple but not a mango, and she has a mango but not an apple
I have an mango but not a apple, and she has a apple but not an mango
I hanve a mago but not an anpple, ad she hans an anpple but not a mago
```

Is there a way to input a list or dictionary (like in python) so I can define the swaps and don't need to use **strings.ReplaceAll()** multiple times.

For example:

> apple -> mango
>
> mango -> apple
>
> a -> an
>
> an -> a

**Desired Output:**

```
 I have a mango but not an apple, and she has an apple but not a mango
```

I will be glad to learn about pros and cons of each, if there are multiple ways to do this.

Answer (score 4):

[`strings.ReplaceAll()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#ReplaceAll) does not perform "switching", it just replaces the occurrences of *some* string with *another*; but it doesn't execute replacing *another* with *some*. Meaning `ReplaceAll(s, "a", "b")` will replace all occurrences of `"a"` with `"b"`, but it will not replace occurrences of `"b"` with `"a"`.

That's 2 replace operations. And these 2 replace operations can't be executed sequentially, because once you replace "apple"s with "mango"s, you'll only have "mango"s and so if you'd replace "mango"s with "apple"s, you'd be left with "apple"s only.

Instead you may use [`strings.Replacer`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Replacer) where you may list multiple replaceable pairs, and its [`Replacer.Replace()`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Replacer.Replace) method will perform all replaces in one step.

Also note that you should not replace all "a"s with "an" as there could be other "a"s in your input, not just before "mango". So best is if you replace "an apple" with "a mango" and vice versa.

```
s := "I have an apple but not a mango, and she has a mango but not an apple"
fmt.Println(s)

r := strings.NewReplacer("an apple", "a mango", "a mango", "an apple")
s = r.Replace(s)
fmt.Println(s)
```

Output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://play.golang.org/p/wWRqXvghh_O)):

```
I have an apple but not a mango, and she has a mango but not an apple
I have a mango but not an apple, and she has an apple but not a mango
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate the meaning of your first sentence? Also, if r.WriteString(w, s) is a shorthand of r.Replace(s) + write_to_file , or it is something different?

Comment: @muruDiaz See edited answer. And yes, `Replacer.WriteString()` performs a `r.Replace(s)` and writes the result to `w`, but it does it more efficiently than these 2 steps performed sequentially.